# Constraint layout's unknown behaviour

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to make a simple UI using constraint layout. The UI appears fine in layout editor but when I run it on a device whole UI is messed up. The UI here is used as a row_item for Recyclerview to list different items
I think there is a problem in my code regarding constraints.

### **Simple layout in my layout-editor:**

[image: This is what i want]

### **Output that i get:**

[image]

layout.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/gray_light"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitleRow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_16dp"
        android:text="@string/view_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgArrow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgRow"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSubtitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_16dp"
        android:text="@string/view_subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgArrow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgRow"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtTitleRow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_right" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use RelativeLayout instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRow"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/text_gray"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"
        android:tint="@color/text_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitleRow"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:text="name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgRow"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgArrow"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSubtitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:text="subtitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitleRow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgRow"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgArrow"/>

    <!-- Remaining Note:Set border of button like playstore button-->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgArrow"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"
        android:tint="@color/text_black"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No it's not about image but textviews not constrained properly. I think .so.

Comment: just try my code. textView will automatically get adjusted

Comment: Sorry buddy, the second image that i put was wrong. See the updated question.

Comment: have you tried my code in that just adjust the  layout_width and layout_height of the ImageView as your preferences from 80dp .I also had that problem and this is how i solved it

Comment: does the issue remains the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168664/discussion-between-pranav-ashok-and-shukla-swapnil).

Comment: Actually I am using this constraint layout UI as a row inside  recyclerview.

Comment: @ShuklaSwapnil just try it

Comment: @ShuklaSwapnil i have change the layout to RelativeLayout

Comment: Yes I was able to make the layout work using relative layout but i want to do it with constraint layout. But +1 for your answer.

Comment: So for a dummy row what you prefer :A relative or constraint layout.